# Getting all files that contain string in array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to use PHP to get an array of all of the filenames within a directory that match any strings in an array.

The array of strings to search looks like this:

```
$users = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
```

What I am hoping to get is a list of files matching any of these strings back in an array like this:

```
$files = array('user1_resume.pdf', 'user1_statement.pdf', 'user2_resume.pdf');
```

How should I do this in PHP?

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches only?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @Anonymous no I am not. Results like if I did `ls user1* user2* user3*`

Comment: http://php.net/preg_grep http://php.net/foreach

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard The problem is that I am unaware of how I could accomplish this. I was thinking readdir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and then using preg_grep but it seems like there would be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function glob.

```
$users = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
$searchString = implode(',',$users);
$result = glob('*{' . $searchString . '}*',GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Quote from source above:

```
GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'
```

**[Edit]**

If the filename must start with whatever is in your list of users just remove the first asterix in the example above.

Comment: It also needs to be in a specific directory. Would this work fine with this method: `glob('html/upload' . '{' . $searchString . '}*',GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: That would work fine with a little bit of change in your code, because you forgot one slash. You can even skip the delimiter you're using for the braces. `glob('html/upload/{' . $searchString . '}*',GLOB_BRACE);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's not most efficient solution but it's clear

```
$users = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
$files = array('user1_resume.pdf', 'user1_statement.pdf', 'user2_resume.pdf');


// to read from directory
//$files = scandir($dirName);



$resultFiles = array();
foreach($files as $file){
 foreach($users as $user){
    if(strpos($file,$user) !== null)
        $resultFiles[] = $file;
 }
}

echo "array:" .print_r( array_unique($resultFiles), true);
```